# How do we go on about harmonizing plainchant on keyboards?

Tags: harmony

[image: Transcription]

We start on sol and use sol-la-si/ti. We have two finalis: sancti ends on sol but amen ends on la. The recitation is la. Hypophrygian, I think, has recitation tone la with mi as finalis. But I cannot find the mode for this simple melody. In modern music we would say that Signum Crucis starts on Do and end on do with amen ending on re which is not an ending tone.  How do we go on about harmonizing it on keyboards?
I only want to harmonize as I am learning to play the organ.
It has nothing to do with school assignments nor even a lesson from my organ teacher although I will ask him about this.  The other question was about the mode of the tune. This is all about how to harmonize the melody.

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing. Is this a class assignment? What are you harmonizing it. Historically a chant would have been sung in unison, later styles would have harmonized the chant in perfect fifths (organum.)

Comment: This is a dup. The same question was posted a few minutes before by the same user.

Comment: @b3ko By my read they are slightly different questions. The other one asks what key the piece is in and is off-topic. This one seems more on-topic but might be too broad.

Comment: @todd_wilcox ah yes. I guess the last sentence is different.

Comment: I'd say this is aeolian mode (even it starts with an upbeat (sol). I would harmonize it with em and am.

Comment: Not a dupe, the other asks about what mode; this one asks how to harmonise it.

Comment: As the excellent answer provided so far leads with "You could go in many directions..." that confirms my earlier impression that this question is too broad. Generally there are far too many ways to harmonize any melody to have a clear, concise answer without having some limitations on the harmonization.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I see. You're right, but I think with some editing this could be narrow enough for this site. VTCed.

Answer (score 1):

You could go in many directions to harmonize it given that you don't have any assignment or 'rules' to follow.

Personally, I like these two options:

- treat it like [organum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organum). Start on a unison, hold the chant tone long enough for the harmonizing voice to move up by steps to a perfect fifth, once the perfect fifth has been reached both voices continue in parallel perfect fifths, end it with a *[clausula vera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence#Clausula_vera)*.

This is organum in fourths:

[image]

- more fun would be to treat it like Erik Satie's *Ogives*. Make several statements of the the chant each with a different texture.

  - in octaves (could be fifths too, I suppose)
  - maintain parallel octaves in treble & bass, but fill in the inner voices using only major/minor triads, use inversions, cadence points in root position
  - harmonize with all root position, major/minor triads, a new independent bass is used
  - repeat the second harmonization.

[image]